# How to handle redis pub/sub in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, socket.io, rake

I have a rails app which talks to a socket.io app  via Redis.
I can create a message on the rails app and socket.io broadcasts it, but I have no idea how to handle the incoming messages (i.e. I want a service to always be listening to Redis and process the incoming messages).
Can you please tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: I suggest reading this article http://old.blog.phusion.nl/2008/08/25/daemon_controller-a-library-for-robust-daemon-management/ although îs a bit old ...but it still works..or You can check out this gem https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons.  Basically You will have to have a daemon in which You can call Faye.subscribe to the socket.io. Channel and receive the messages in real time basically.

Comment: Or maybe using ActionCable ...but honestly i never used until now...șo i can't give You details about that

Answer (score 0):

you can use sidekiq gem here which is by default using redis so whenever you enqueue a job to redis via *perform_later* method provided by sidekiq. Sidekiq worker will run it whenever a worker is free.
For Pub/sub as you mentioned in the header you can go for Action Cable feature provided by Rails.

Comment: With the ActionCable, you open a socket when requested. But I want this process to be listening to the Redis as soon as the app starts and remains listening forever.

Comment: how can I do that?